# Discord Embed : Is there a way to make the embed columns bigger ? Or prevent line breaks?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

So I'm messing around with embeds because I just discovered them and I want to make a nice display of all the players of my team. I already have the data storing and commands and all, so my question is really just about embeds.

In the embed, each field should correspond to a player. Here is how it looks now :
[image]

To me it looks really nice, but there are some annoying line breaks in the values which don't look good at all

I would like to make the columns larger, if it's possible

Also, I tried making 2 columns instead of 3 to make them larger, but it's not very convenient to make because I had to include an empty-char line in between all the lines, and it takes up too many fields for nothing which makes it even less convenient. Is there a way to make 2 columns ? This is what it looks so far with 2 columns :
[image]

Comment: There is no real way to format the embeds really well besides just string formatting in the fields. I would look into empty space characters such as `\u00b`. You can use this to have "empty" columns of an embed. But it's still kinda janky.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, no, this is just a Discord limitation.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately the embeds are resized according to the screen size

Comment: I have a doubt about this. I edited my original message so you can see how it looks if I screenshot the entire screen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer, but rather a comment

Comment: @Chuaat actually that's the answer of the question, embeds in discord are resized according to the screen size, yes fou can still try to format it using strings, but it won't looks the same on other screens. I'm sorry but I can't make up an answer that doesn't exist.  Instead of commenting here, you could have simply replied to the person concerned directly